# Show HTML content wit PHP (and load style)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have some HTML pages (in "web" folder) that use some styles and scripts, and i need to show these HTML pages using a PHP script. Here is a simplified version of the code i'm using:

```
<?php

 readfile("web/index.html");
```

It works but it doesn't load any resources (css, js, images) because the URLs are not absolute :

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
 <link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

It doesn't find the resources because it's looking for the css folder in the same folder as the PHP script.

Any workaround for this ?

Comment: The urls used for css, js and images does not need to be absolute. In fact you'd want them relative as it will make it easier to migrate your website to another domain in the future. As for your problem I suggest simply fixing the relative path so it no longer looks in the same folder as your PHP script.

Comment: @Mathyn The problem is that i have hundreds of HTML pages and i prefer not to change them. and each HTML has different resources so i can't just takes these folders to the root folder as the have the same names.

Comment: Ah right good point. I think @Uwe Ohse's answer might help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add add `<base href='...'>` into the html, like this (not tested):

```
$page_content=preg_replace("%</head%i","<base href='web/'></head",$page_content);
```

insert this after the readfile. See [MDN web docs for more information about that tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

In some browsers (Firefox and edge at least) it also works if you print the base tag before you output $page_content. It's dirty, but maybe it's good enough.

Comment: It works, Thank you!
If anyone has a cleaner way please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can use something like this

index.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <php include("menu.php"); ?>
 </head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

menu.php

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

for base path use some variable like `$base = "http://localhost"` then use your elements like `<img scr="<?php $base ?>/images/myimage.jpg" />`

Hope this answers your question